# Jquery JSON decode multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this multiple set of data as array

```
data = [{"id": "1", "name" : "abc", "key1" : "value12 }, {"id": "2", "name" : "cde", "key2" : "value2" }.....]
```

I need to get this data using jQuery

```
json = $.parseJSON(data);
```

but how do I access the parsed JSON data? `json.id` shows the result as undefined.

Thanks

**Update :** Sorry I fixed the above example JSON I gave, I just quickly typed it by myself and it's not the original json I'm having trouble with. I just gave it to give an idea about the problem that I was having. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: That looks like invalid JSON to me. There should be commas in between each object. You have an array of objects. Accessing the id of the first object in the collection would be json[0].id.

Comment: @cpreid sorry about that, i fixed the json, i just typed it myself, the original json is json_encode by php so the original JSON is not wrong, i just made an example to give an idea about the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't JSON. It isn't even JavaScript.

If you fix the syntax errors (such as the missing quotes and the missing commas between the array items) then it is an array literal (containing object literals which contain …). **Don't** `parseJSON` it (you use that on JSON texts stored in JavaScript strings).

Since it is an array. It doesn't have an id. It has a number of numerical indexes.

```
var someObject = data[0];
```

The objects stored on those indexes have ids.

```
var id = someObject.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid. ',' are missing between objects.

Suppose if json is :

```
data = [{"id": "1", "name" : "abc", "key1" : "value12" }, {"id": "2", "name" : "cde", "key2" : "value2" }]
```

Then you can access 'id' element using this :

```
data[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = '{"id": "1", "name" : "abc", "key1" : "value12" } , {"id": "2", "name" : "cde", "key2" : "value2"}';
var obj = JSON.parse('[' + data + ']');
alert(obj[0].id);
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/6JnFp/)

Answer (score -1):

Your json is invalid,

```
data = [{"id": "1", "name" : "abc", "key1" : "value12" }, {"id": "2", "name" : "cde", "key2" : "value2" }.....]
```

Retrive using:

```
var id =  data[0].id;

console.log(id);
```

Comment: Mr.Downvoters, May I know the reason for Downvoting?